# Issue in making TextBlock invisible using Visibilty.Collapsed (WP7)

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am trying to make the `TextBlocks` collapsed (invisible) but still get a space/line even though the `TextBlocks` are invisible.
 I have seen on many posts that to make a `TextBlock` completely invisible (no line space), the visibility property - `Collapsed` is used.

Please find the code given below, and let me know what I am doing wrong.  I have seen very similiar posts but those do not answer this issue.

Silverlight(WPF) code :

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
        x:Class="AndBI.MainGamePage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
        SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="All is well" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,-14">
            <Button Content="Go" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,29,0,0" Name="GO" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Click="GO_Click" />
            <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,29,0,0" Name="textBox1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="244" DataContext="{Binding}">
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,50,0,0" Name="c10" Text="?" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,285,0,0" Name="b10" Text="aa" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Foreground="#FFFE6943" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" Margin="176,285,0,0" Name="user10" Text="bb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFE6943" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="111" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,285,0,0" Name="c11" Text="cc" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Foreground="#FFFE6943" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Button Content="Scratch Pad" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="262,207,0,0" Name="SP" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Click="SP_Click" />
            <ListBox Height="57" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,144,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="434" >
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition  />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Text1" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Text2" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="Text3" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

C# code behind:

```
private void CollapseAll(TextBlock tb, Boolean visible)
{
    tb.Visibility = (!visible) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}

/**Based upon a criteria the TextBlocks are made invisible as in collapsed**/ 

CollapseAll(c10,false);  
CollapseAll(b10,false);    
CollapseAll(user10,false);  
......................
......................  
/**Based upon a criteria the TextBlocks are made visible**/ 
CollapseAll(c10,true);  
CollapseAll(b10,true);    
CollapseAll(user10,true);
```

Comment: You code looks correct to me. What are you TextBlocks contained within?

Comment: As Colin asks, what is your container? Setting visibility to Collapsed is the correct method to completely remove them, so something else is going wrong. Can you post your entire Xaml for the page?

Comment: can you create a mockup of what you're trygin to create? there's some confusion on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I have posted the entire XAML for the page. Please review. thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ali this code shows what you're ddoing , not what you're trying to achieve. It is not clear what you mean by the first sentence of your question. What is the "space/line" you refer to and how does this relate to the control you've made invisible?

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that all the margins result in all the margin. I would recommand that you use the different layout contains and use the margin only to increase the free space around the element for better usage and not for layout purposes.

Comment: If you set visibility to collapsed the elements (and their margins)  are removed from the visual tree. Margins have nothing to do with his problem. Sorry

Comment: That's true but the margin of the still visible elements or the layout container defines some min hights/width's? I can't say this for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want items to still take up space on the page but not be visible, rather than change the controls visibility, set it's opacity to zero instead.
This allows it to remain in the visualtree and still take up sapce.
If you set visibility to collapsed it is removed from the visual tree.

Comment: He is trying to remove them completely and leave no gap (but something is not working) so while this answer is informative, it is not very helpful. Sorry.

Comment: have posted the entire XAML for the page. Please review. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set the height/width to 0 when it should not be visible